# How to delete a gem path?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, path

How can I delete the second path (`/home/tom/.gem/ruby/1.8`) of `GEM PATHS:` ?

Here's the output of `$ gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/tom/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override in your ~/.bashrc file?

```
#in ~/.bashrc
export GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Feels kind of hacky though.

Answer (score 11):

You can’t! I also wanted to do it, and haven’t found a way. Then I looked for in RubyGems source (at github.com) and learned that it tries to get the path from `etc/gemrc` and `~/.gemrc`. If it fails (and fails `GEM_PATH` environment variable too), it assumes `~/.gem` to be the default path.

Therefore, Max William is right, and you have either to export `GEM_PATH` or to create a `~/.gemrc`. And it’s not a hack, for sure! :-)

Hope to have cleared things a bit!

Comment: Cheers, this was driving me nuts!